# Getting error while accessing Microsoft Excel Online Workbook using httr package in R

Tags: r, sharepoint, microsoft-graph-api, onedrive

Using httr package...i tried to get the access of the excel sheet online...using following command:

```
resp <- POST("https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/drive/items/{45B5B145-0A1C-43B8-BF67-97B5EC21AD13}/workbook/createSession", add_headers("Content-Type" = "application/json",authorization = "Bearer {access-token}"))
```

But I am getting the following error:

```
$error
$error$code
[1] "InvalidAuthenticationToken"

$error$message
[1] "CompactToken parsing failed with error code: -2147184105"

$error$innerError
$error$innerError$`request-id`
[1] "538743c2-a0d9-451b-ba8c-5e59bcd1330f"

$error$innerError$date
[1] "2017-05-23T09:02:43"
```

I followed the following documentation on Microsoft Graph to access the excel sheets online: https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/v1.0/resources/excel

In this, the following rest call is given to access the sheet:

```
POST/{version}/me/drive/items/01CYZLFJGUJ7JHBSZDFZFL25KSZGQTVAUN/workbook/createSession

content-type: Application/Json 
authorization: Bearer {access-token}

{ "persistChanges": true }
```

How to do the above rest call using POST function of httr package to avoid the above mentioned error and access the sheet?

Comment: Is this OneDrive Consumer or Business?

Comment: The "itemId" specified isn't for consumer or for business so that's one problem. But the request is failing due to a bad access token - how was that obtained?